# Create set of Python functions

Tags: python, function, class, constructor, sqlalchemy

I would like to create a number of functions which start by calling one particular function, and end by calling another.

Each function would take a different number of arguments, but they would share the first and last line. Is this possible?

To give you an example, I am trying to use this to create a set of functions which can connect to my database via sqlalchemy, add an entry to it, and exit nicely:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from os import path
from common_classes import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def loadSession():
    db_path = "sqlite:///" + path.expanduser("~/animal_data.db")
    engine = create_engine(db_path, echo=False)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    return session, engine

def add_animal(id_eth, cage_eth, sex, ear_punches, id_uzh="", cage_uzh=""):
    session, engine = loadSession()
    new_animal = Animal(id_eth=id_eth, cage_eth=cage_eth, sex=sex, ear_punches=ear_punches, id_uzh=id_uzh, cage_uzh=cage_uzh)
    session.add(new_animal)
    commit_and_close(session, engine)

def add_genotype(name, zygosity):
    session, engine = loadSession()
    new_genotype = Genotype(name=name, zygosity=zygosity)
    session.add(new_animal)
    commit_and_close(session, engine)

def commit_and_close(session, engine):
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

Again, what I am trying to do is collapse `add_animal()` and `add_genotype()` (and prospectively many more functions) into a single constructor.

I have thought maybe I can use a class for this, and while I believe `loadSession()` could be called from `__init__` I have no idea how to call the `commit_and_close()` function at the end - nor how to manage the variable number of arguments of every subclass...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `add_X` functions for every type `X`, just create a single `add` function that adds an object which you create on the “outside” of the funcition:

So `add_animal(params…)` becomes `add(Animal(params…))`, and `add_genotype(params…)` becomes `add(Genotype(params…))`.

That way, your `add` function would just look like this:

```
def add (obj):
    session, engine = loadSession()
    session.add(obj)
    commit_and_close(session, engine)
```

Then it’s up to the caller of that function to create the object, which opens up the interface and allows you to get objects from elsewhere too. E.g. something like this would be possible too then:

```
for animal in zoo.getAnimals():
    add(animal)
```